# Wrong min value from ArcGIS 10.4 zonal statistics as table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, zonal-statistics, srtm, arcgis-10.4

I used the zonal statistics as table tool in ArcGIS10.4 to calculate SRTM, the in_zone is a gridded shapefile, the in_value_Raster is the SRTM extracted for the region as in the image (90m x90m). The result table gave me min values of 1 and 0, which does not match the input raster at all. I would like to know what might be causing this problem and how to solve it. Ignore NoData option was checked. Both input shapefile and raster have the same spatial reference system:WGS84. I also converted them into UTM but the min value still didnt make any sense. [image: input zone layer (grids) and input raster layer]
[image: output table, inputs referenced with WGS84]
[image: output table, inputs referenced with UTM]
[image: complete stats]

Comment: It may have to do with the number of unique values in your raster and/or the range of values in your raster. There are some limitations that ESRI should make more explicit. There's not much or clear documentation on the limitations, but see: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00501-00525-000521.htm and http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/010001-020000/tool-errors-and-warnings-10351-10375-010367.htm. So, you may be getting an artificial wrap-around of values.

Comment: there is a bug shifting the column, your 0 and 1 are the area (in degree, rounded) and the very large values are your areas in meters. I mentioned it in another answer, but I don't remember which was the exact question. Anyway, read your table by replacing count with ID, area with count, min with max ... and you'll get the consistent values.

Comment: Thank you Tom, I reset the limit for raster under options.

Comment: @radouxju, could you maybe describe how exactly the columns are shifted? My statistic selection was 'ALL', please see the last image. If I shift all the columns to the next column my MEDIAN column would not have any rows to match, thank you.

Comment: Indeed you loose the last column. If you need the median you need to specifically ask for it.

Comment: Does anybody know if/when Esri is going to fix the bug in the Zonal Statistics for Table Tool in ArcGIS 10.4?

Comment: I just found an issue w/ ZonalStatisticsAsTable as well while testing in a 10.4.1 environment (comparing to a 10.2 env).  I am only obtaining the MEAN, and those values are definitely way off in 10.4.1.  10.3 produces correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, let's hope that it will solved soon because you loose the median column. The Feature ID header is missing then all column header are shifhted one step left.

[image]

Comment: re: 'This is a bug'.  By a bug, do you mean document as a bug by esri?  If so, is there a bug number to track when it has been resolved?

Comment: @Rex there is no bug report as far as I know.  I call it a bug because the tool does not work as expected, and it work properly in previous versions.

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing and it appears that when you use your 'OBJECTID' as your zonal field, it cant add it as a column in the output so it causes a miss-match between the columns and the headers (column names).  The workaround is to use a different column as your zonal field in your input and your columns should line up in your output.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the zonal statistics as table again with all the setting identical to the previous try on arcGIS 10.3x and got the correct output with all the desired columns (Image as below).

[image: new output column using arcGIS 10.3x]